# creating a laplacian pyramid in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

My question is about image processing. I want to create a laplacian pyramid and display the levels of the pyramid in matlab. I read the images by this line:

```
imga = im2double(imread('img.jpg'));
```

and I wanted to create the laplacian pyramid with this line:

```
limga = genPyr(imga,'lap',level);
```

finally I wanted to display first level of the pyramid with this line:

```
imshow(limga{1});
```

but I had an error like this:

"Undefined function 'genPyr' for input arguments of type 'double'"

I searched the error in google but I could not reach the solution.

But there is a usage in matlab about this usage: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30790-image-pyramidgaussian-and-laplacian/content/pyrBlend.m

Where is the mistake? Can you help me?

Thank you,

Comment: make sure that file is in the matlab path you are at.

Comment: I am sure, I can display the image before these processes.

Comment: genPyr is a user-contributed function packaged in that File Exchange page that you mention.  You need to download the package from that site and put the M-files it contains on your MATLAB path.

Comment: Thank you Peter, This comment was useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the [whole submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30790-image-pyramidgaussian-and-laplacian?download=true) on the page. You probably missed some functions or didn't put all of them in your working path.

Comment: Pretty sure you are on the right track. I wrote a similar answer with more details, but inspired by yours.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to lennon310's answer and @Peter's comment:

You are pointing to the Mathworks file exchange. This is where third parties put code you can download (for free) to enhance the capabilities of Matlab.  I have the feeling you did not download / install the package.  You can check this by typing

```
which genPyr
```

at the command prompt in Matlab. Very likely it cannot be found. If you are SURE you have downloaded it, it's possible that you did not add the path to the files to your Matlab path. You can add this path from the command line, or from the UI:

```
path(path, 'path/to/genPyr');
```

should do it.

Comment: Thank you Floris, I hadn't downloaded the package, problem was solved.